# How can I check what hardware my iPhone app is running on?

Tags: iphone

I'm writing an app that needs to function differently if it is running on different models of the iPhone/iPod Touch. How can I check if the app is running on 3GS, 3G or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See here:

[how do I detect whether I have iPhone 2G,3G,3GS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543925/how-do-i-detect-whether-i-have-iphone-2g-3g-3gs/1546070#1546070)

Answer (score 2):

The [`UIDevice`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) class provides some information like this.

But you're probably *much* better off testing for capabilities ("does this device support compass headings?") than for specific models ("is this device a 3GS?"). What is it that you're trying to do?

**Edit:** for the specific example I presented above, see the [`headingAvailable`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLLocationManager/headingAvailable) property of `CLLocationManager`. It will be `YES` if and only if heading information can be obtained from the device.

Comment: You hit on what I'm trying to do actually. I want to support the compass when it is available and when it isn't, do something else entirely.