# How to detect iphone4s

Tags: ios, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-ios)

I am using [UIDevice (Hardware) by Erica Sadun](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension) to detect the device info.
How to detect if it's an iphone4s device?

Comment: It is always better you check certain capabilities are present rather than checking for device model..

Comment: @Krishnabhadra Just wants to get the device model when got a bug report.

Comment: This post gives a sample code you could use to do what you need : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk

Answer (score -2):

To detect a specific model, you would need to test for some capability that only that model has, so to detect an iPhone 3GS, check for a video capability on the camera:

```
#define SOURCETYPE UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera

// does the device have a camera?
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:SOURCETYPE]) {
  // if so, does that camera support video?
  NSArray *mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:SOURCETYPE];
  bool isA3GS = [mediaTypes containsObject:kUTTypeMovie];
}
```

reference: [how do I detect whether I have iPhone 2G,3G,3GS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543925/how-do-i-detect-whether-i-have-iphone-2g-3g-3gs)

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk> add your iPhone 4s too into the list and use the class. I hope this should be helpful to you.

Comment: this cannot be an answer