# How to programmatically differentiate between iphone 4 and iphone 4S?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working on app which needs to check the iphone model, but I'm not able to find any solution.  I will be thank full for any suggestion.

Answer (score 59):

This is much simpler one. ***SIMPLE ENOUGH FOR JUST COPY & PASTE***

Also, I've included matching model name for machine name.

```
//MARK: Required import
#import <sys/utsname.h>

+ (NSString*)deviceModelName {

    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    NSString *machineName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //MARK: More official list is at
    //http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models
    //MARK: You may just return machineName. Following is for convenience

    NSDictionary *commonNamesDictionary =
    @{
      @"i386":     @"iPhone Simulator",
   @"x86_64":   @"iPad Simulator",

   @"iPhone1,1":    @"iPhone",
   @"iPhone1,2":    @"iPhone 3G",
   @"iPhone2,1":    @"iPhone 3GS",
   @"iPhone3,1":    @"iPhone 4",
   @"iPhone3,2":    @"iPhone 4(Rev A)",
   @"iPhone3,3":    @"iPhone 4(CDMA)",
   @"iPhone4,1":    @"iPhone 4S",
   @"iPhone5,1":    @"iPhone 5(GSM)",
   @"iPhone5,2":    @"iPhone 5(GSM+CDMA)",
   @"iPhone5,3":    @"iPhone 5c(GSM)",
   @"iPhone5,4":    @"iPhone 5c(GSM+CDMA)",
   @"iPhone6,1":    @"iPhone 5s(GSM)",
   @"iPhone6,2":    @"iPhone 5s(GSM+CDMA)",

   @"iPhone7,1":    @"iPhone 6+ (GSM+CDMA)",
   @"iPhone7,2":    @"iPhone 6 (GSM+CDMA)",

   @"iPhone8,1":    @"iPhone 6S (GSM+CDMA)",
   @"iPhone8,2":    @"iPhone 6S+ (GSM+CDMA)",

   @"iPad1,1":  @"iPad",
   @"iPad2,1":  @"iPad 2(WiFi)",
   @"iPad2,2":  @"iPad 2(GSM)",
   @"iPad2,3":  @"iPad 2(CDMA)",
   @"iPad2,4":  @"iPad 2(WiFi Rev A)",
   @"iPad2,5":  @"iPad Mini 1G (WiFi)",
   @"iPad2,6":  @"iPad Mini 1G (GSM)",
   @"iPad2,7":  @"iPad Mini 1G (GSM+CDMA)",
   @"iPad3,1":  @"iPad 3(WiFi)",
   @"iPad3,2":  @"iPad 3(GSM+CDMA)",
   @"iPad3,3":  @"iPad 3(GSM)",
   @"iPad3,4":  @"iPad 4(WiFi)",
   @"iPad3,5":  @"iPad 4(GSM)",
   @"iPad3,6":  @"iPad 4(GSM+CDMA)",

   @"iPad4,1":  @"iPad Air(WiFi)",
   @"iPad4,2":  @"iPad Air(GSM)",
   @"iPad4,3":  @"iPad Air(GSM+CDMA)",

   @"iPad5,3":  @"iPad Air 2 (WiFi)",
   @"iPad5,4":  @"iPad Air 2 (GSM+CDMA)",

   @"iPad4,4":  @"iPad Mini 2G (WiFi)",
   @"iPad4,5":  @"iPad Mini 2G (GSM)",
   @"iPad4,6":  @"iPad Mini 2G (GSM+CDMA)",

   @"iPad4,7":  @"iPad Mini 3G (WiFi)",
   @"iPad4,8":  @"iPad Mini 3G (GSM)",
   @"iPad4,9":  @"iPad Mini 3G (GSM+CDMA)",

   @"iPod1,1":  @"iPod 1st Gen",
   @"iPod2,1":  @"iPod 2nd Gen",
   @"iPod3,1":  @"iPod 3rd Gen",
   @"iPod4,1":  @"iPod 4th Gen",
   @"iPod5,1":  @"iPod 5th Gen",
   @"iPod7,1":  @"iPod 6th Gen",
    };

    NSString *deviceName = commonNamesDictionary[machineName];

    if (deviceName == nil) {
        deviceName = machineName;
    }

    return deviceName;
}
```

Comment: Hi I m new to iOS app Development, n i m trying to use your code, but i m getting error upon using **struct utsname systemInfo;
** , can u pls tell me how to resolve this. **ERROR: Variable has incomplete type'struct utsname'**

Comment: @Bhurudada Do #import <sys/utsname.h> This is not an officially documented framework, but it never caused any problem when submitting your app to App Store

Comment: @Peter: I get on the iPad simulator on a macbook Pro the string `"x86_64"` from: `NSString *modelName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`

Comment: Why not just return an emum? Much simpler than a string.

Comment: @JochemVanDerSpek Added your `x86_64" in the dictionary. Thank you

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, that is what I've never understood. why is the string better than an integer for it, so I'm happy I'm not alone with this concern.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Would you tell me more about the idea of returning enumerated integers? I need to learn

Comment: @petershine `enum`s are excellent where you know all of your data beforehand, as they take up far less space in memory, they can be used in switch statements, and as a general rule are much faster than objects in a scenario like this.

Comment: Some please add new iPhone 6's/iPad Airs/Minis to the list.

Comment: FYI: I am running Xcode 6.3 on a MacBook Pro and the iPhone simulator can also return x86_64.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a common method of retriving the device model.  There are no NS methods for this, so you gotta use c

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString *)machine {
    NSString *machine;
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *name = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.machine", name, &size, NULL, 0);
    machine = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:name];
    free(name);
    return machine;
}
```

Comment: Yup, just include sys/sysctl.h and sys/types.h

Comment: Great, I'll give it a shot. Where do you guys find this stuff? ;)

Comment: That link doesnt work for me.  Keep getting a database connection error.

Answer (score 5):

```
Update a list of devices: 
In future will be updated with iPad 4.
+  (NSString*)deviceModelName {
/*
 @"i386"      on the simulator
 @"x86_64"    on the simulator
 @"iPod1,1"   on iPod Touch
 @"iPod2,1"   on iPod Touch Second Generation
 @"iPod3,1"   on iPod Touch Third Generation
 @"iPod4,1"   on iPod Touch Fourth Generation
 @"iPod5,1"   on iPod Touch Fourth Generation
 @"iPhone1,1" on iPhone
 @"iPhone1,2" on iPhone 3G
 @"iPhone2,1" on iPhone 3GS
 @"iPad1,1"   on iPad
 @"iPad2,1"   on iPad 2
 @"iPad2,5"   on iPad mini 1
 @"iPad3,1"   on iPad 3
 @"iPhone3,1" on iPhone 4
 @"iPhone4,1" on iPhone 4S
 @"iPhone5,1" on iPhone 5
 */

struct utsname systemInfo;

uname(&systemInfo);

NSString *modelName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

if([modelName isEqualToString:@"i386"] || [modelName isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone Simulator";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 3G";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 3GS";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 4";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 4S";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 5";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPod 1st Gen";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPod 2nd Gen";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPod 3rd Gen";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPod 4th Gen";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPod 5th Gen";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 2(WiFi)";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 2(GSM)";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 2(CDMA)";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 2(WiFi + New Chip)";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad mini (WiFi)";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad mini (GSM)";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 3(WiFi)";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 3(GSM)";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 3(CDMA)";
}

return modelName;
```

}

Answer (score 4):

For my purposes I've written a tiny library that abstracts away the underlying C calls and presents an Objective-C interface.

```
NSLog(@"Big model number: %d", deviceDetails.bigModel);
//Big model number: 4

NSLog(@"Small model number: %d", deviceDetails.smallModel);
//Small model number: 1

if (deviceDetails.model == GBDeviceModeliPhone4S) {
    NSLog(@"It's a 4S");
}
//It's a 4S

if (deviceDetails.family != GBDeviceFamilyiPad) {
    NSLog(@"It's not an iPad");
}
//It's not an iPad

NSLog(@"systemInfo string: %@", [GBDeviceInfo rawSystemInfoString]);
//systemInfo string: iPhone4,1
```

It's on github: [GBDeviceInfo](https://github.com/lmirosevic/GBDeviceInfo)

Answer (score 4):

Use this code. This is a full list of any actual iDevice and the Model number, the list can be updated easily by checking http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models .

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);

NSString *modelName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSString *machinename = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


NSString *modelnumber = @"?";

//Simulator
if([modelName isEqualToString:@"i386"] || [modelName isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone Simulator";
}

//iPhone
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone";
    modelnumber = @"A1203";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 3G";
    modelnumber = @"A1241/A1324";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 3GS";
    modelnumber = @"A1303/A1325";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 4 (GSM)";
    modelnumber = @"A1332";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 4 GSM Rev A";
    modelnumber = @"?";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 4 (CDMA)";
    modelnumber = @"A1349";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 4S";
    modelnumber = @"A1387/A1431";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 5 (GSM)";
    modelnumber = @"A1428";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"]) {
    modelName = @"iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)";
    modelnumber = @"A1429/A1442";
}

//iPod touch
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPod touch 1G";
    modelnumber = @"A1213";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPod touch 2G";
    modelnumber = @"A1288";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPod touch 3G";
    modelnumber = @"A1318";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPod touch 4G";
    modelnumber = @"A1367";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPod touch 5G";
    modelnumber = @"A1421";
}

//iPad
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 1G";
    modelnumber = @"A1219/A1337";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 2 (WiFi)";
    modelnumber = @"A1395";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 2 (GSM)";
    modelnumber = @"A1396";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 2 (CDMA)";
    modelnumber = @"A1397";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 2 (WiFi + Rev A)";
    modelnumber = @"A1395";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 3 (WiFi)";
    modelnumber = @"A1416";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)";
    modelnumber = @"A1403";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 3 (GSM)";
    modelnumber = @"A1430";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 4 (WiFi)";
    modelnumber = @"A1458";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 4 (GSM)";
    modelnumber = @"A1459";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)";
    modelnumber = @"A1460";
}

//iPad mini
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad mini (WiFi)";
    modelnumber = @"A1432";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad mini (GSM)";
    modelnumber = @"A1454";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"]) {
    modelName = @"iPad mini (GSM+CDMA)";
    modelnumber = @"A1455";
}

//Apple TV, just for funn:)
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"AppleTV2,1"]) {
    modelName = @"Apple TV 2G";
    modelnumber = @"A1378";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,1"]) {
    modelName = @"Apple TV 3G";
    modelnumber = @"A1427";
}
else if([modelName isEqualToString:@"AppleTV3,2"]) {
    modelName = @"Apple TV 3G (Rev A)";
    modelnumber = @"A1469";
}

NSLog(@"Device model: %@/ %@",modelName,modelnumber);
```

This could be the output: `Device model: iPhone 4 GSM/ iPhone3,1`

Answer (score 2):

Try using following : you will get all the detail informations of the Device...

```
NSLog(@"uniqueIdentifier: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"name: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);
NSLog(@"systemName: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemName]);
NSLog(@"systemVersion: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
NSLog(@"model: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] model]);
NSLog(@"localizedModel: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] localizedModel]);
```

If above does not work for you then use [github project](https://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension)

**EDIT :**

Whether you are on an iPhone or a iPod Touch:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *systemName = [device systemName];
```

To detect the version of the OS:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *systemVersion = [device systemVersion];
```

For Reference:
[how do I detect whether I have iPhone 2G,3G,3GS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543925/how-do-i-detect-whether-i-have-iphone-2g-3g-3gs)

Comment: Unfortunately, none of these will differentiate between 4 and 4S.

Comment: Thanks DShah i have gone through the project but its for the older version i think and the [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] returns only model not particular model type.(eg iPhone4s,iphone4).

Answer (score 2):

However if you are running application on simulator, you will never get device name as "iPhone 6" of "iPhone6+" or anything like that. I am currently using `Xcode Version 6.2 (6C131e)` in which I have successfully checked device type even on simulator using few macros. Those are

```
// ******************* DEVICE INDENTIFICATION MACROS *****************//
#define IS_IPAD             (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
#define IS_IPHONE           (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
#define IS_IPHONE4          (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE5          (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
#define IS_IPHONE6          (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE6PLUS      (IS_IPHONE && [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736.0)
#define IS_RETINA           ([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(displayLinkWithTarget:selector:)] && ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0))
```