# User Agent string for IPhone 4S

Tags: iphone

Since the WURFL User-Agent Database went commercial there seems to be no public central database for browser user agents. Since i do not own an Iphone4 mayself it would be really helpful if someone could answer me this easy question and/or point me to a WURFL alternative :)

So - what is the User-Agent string of the IPhone 4s? 
Is it any different from the IPhone4 version?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Apple User Agents do not expose the hardware version, so you can only guess the iPhone version by the OS version, for example, if it's running iOS 5, it must be an iPhone 4 or 4S.  In fact, it's even very hard (perhaps impossible) to [distinguish between iPhone 4 and 4S from native apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292246/how-to-programmatically-differentiate-between-iphone-4-and-iphone-4s).

Anyway, the other answer is incorrect, that UA must be from an iPhone 3, 3GS or a really outdated iPhone 4, but it cannot be from a 4S because [the 4S shipped with iOS 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone_4S#Operating_system).  Here's a selection of iPhone 4/4S UAs I've seen today:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A405
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A406
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ver sion/5.1 Mobile/9A405 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A405 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A406 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9A334
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9A334 Safari/7534.48.3
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3
```

With regards to WURFL, I am the COO of ScientiaMobile (WURFL owner), and I can say that no public access to our data has been removed since our formation.  You are welcome to browse our devices and user agents at the [ScientiaMobile WURFL Explorer](http://dbapi.scientiamobile.com/explore).

Comment: +1 for WURFL. Also commenting to reiterate that it's still free for non-commercial use (AGPL for stand alone installation, not cloud/service based), but now more strictly controlled for commercial use.

Comment: Following the WURFL database link now returns the message "This site is not meant for public use." I guess policies change in a year and a half. The second link looks useful, but many of the links don't work on an iPhone at least.

Comment: Indeed, I posted a link to our internal tool instead of our public-facing one.  I've updated the link in the post!

Answer (score 4):

iphone:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5
```

ipod Touch:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPod; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3_3 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0.2 Mobile/8J2 Safari/6533.18.5
```

i think the only difference is the software version of different phones