# How to distinguish between iPhone 4 and iPhone 4s in javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios

I have an app which can only run from iPhone 4s and up, I need to be able to distinguish on the client side (i.e. javascript) the device, and load the app or redirect accordingly.
Is there any way to detect it?
thanks

Comment: is my answer a good starting point for you to solve this checking? reply if you need more information or questions!

Comment: thanks, it was useful in helping me realize there's no way to distinguish between 4 and 4s on client side and find my solution elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see these three options for you:

1) use a **precooked open source script** to check this and based on the result you do a redirect. You can use this for example: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/

2) you **implement a javascript** which do a checking based on the navigator parameters. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8348139/detect-ios-version-less-than-5-with-javascript) and a quote code from that SO answer.

> ```
> function iOSversion() {
>   if (/iP(hone|od|ad)/.test(navigator.platform)) {
>     var v = (navigator.appVersion).match(/OS (\d+)_(\d+)_?(\d+)?/);
>     return [parseInt(v[1], 10), parseInt(v[2], 10), parseInt(v[3] || 0, 10)];
>   }
> }
> ```

3.) you can use rewrite rules at **Apache side to redirect** to the proper page based on user-agent. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005153/auto-detect-mobile-browser-via-user-agent).

For all 3 options you have a problem that it is hardly possible to distinguish between iPhone 4 and 4s. See this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548012/user-agent-string-for-iphone-4s).

To mention only if you have to check retina capability you can use this JS too:

```
var isRetina = window.matchMedia("(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)").matches;
```

More info what is min-device-pixel-ratio here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785643/what-exactly-is-device-pixel-ratio).
Also info on media queries here: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Media_queries#-moz-device-pixel-ratio)