# How can I support iPhone 4S, but not iPhone 4?

Tags: ios, device, iphone-4

It's important that my game runs at 60 frames per second. It does on iPhone 4S and 5, but 4 is a world away from 60.

So - without going into whether it's a good idea to or not - how do I prevent iPhone 4 users from buying the game?

Comment: well, it has been asked on stackoverflow quite a few times: "uidevice-extension" and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292246/how-to-programmatically-differentiate-between-iphone-4-and-iphone-4s might help... anyway I would rather aim for not requiring 60 fps and lockout quite a few endusers (willing to pay?)

Comment: That wouldn't prevent a user from downloading the application, which is what this question is trying to achieve. You shouldn't let a user download an app if the device isn't supported, otherwise you'll just anger your users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`, you can lock out certain devices that do not support a capability you require. This really is the only way to prevent an app running an a subset of older generation devices.

To use this, you need to list your capabilities within `Info.plist`. You use the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key, and use an array of capability keys. See the documentation on [iOS Keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html).

For example, to support the iPhone 4S, iPod Touch 5th Gen, and iPad 3rd Gen, you can state that you require the `bluetooth-le` capability, which is Bluetooth Low Energy. A compatability matrix that links capabilities with devices can [be found here](http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/30/uirequireddevicecapabilities-and-device-compatibility-matrix).

**Note:** This does not mean I suggest you should do this; just that you can. It's a very hacky way to do it, and I can't guarantee that Apple won't crack down on it. Ideally you should be able to fallback to lesser (yet acceptable) performance, so that a wider audience can use your application.

Comment: I want to support iPad 2/3/4/Mini, iPhone 4S/5 and equivalent iPod touches, (which I think is just the 5th gen).

Looks like bluetooth-le would kill iPad2. Bummer.

Comment: It runs around 30 frames on a 4.. Which kinda isn't what my company is about. But looks like it'll have to stay supported.

Front facing camera it is then! Thank you all.

Comment: Well, put out a new build to test, and asked if it was acceptable. It's running at about 30, whereas the last build was about 20-25. People have said the previous build was already acceptable...

Nothing to worry about it would seem!  :D

Comment: From personal experience, this is a guaranteed way to have Apple reject your app from being approved for the app store.