# How to specify iOS hardware support?

Tags: ios

We can specify which iOS version our app supports, is there a way to specify which iOS hardware our app supports? (for example, iPad 2 and up)

Comment: Here is a question that has answers which will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/q/1543925/937822

Answer (score 2):

No, not directly. But, I believe you can specify the product family (iPhone vs. iPad), as well as the required device capabilities (e.g. camera, etc.). The combination these two effectively accomplish what you're looking for, though. See [Declaring the Required Device Capabilities in the iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10).