# To detect IOS device type

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have found the solutions from here:
[Determine device (iPhone, iPod Touch) with iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448162/determine-device-iphone-ipod-touch-with-iphone-sdk)

From the link, it suggests to use the library https://gist.github.com/1323251

But obviously the library is quite outdated. I couldn't find the iPhone 5 and new iPad and etc in the list.

Does anyone know how can I find the completed and updated list?

Thank you so much.

Comment: check that http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.ro/2013/01/get-device-model-or-device-type-and.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the updated version of https://gist.github.com/1323251 .
I'll keep it updated when new devices are released.

https://github.com/froztbytes/UIDeviceHardware

Answer (score 31):

you can easily detect `iphone`, `iphone5` and `iPad` with below condition:-

```
 if([[UIDevice currentDevice]userInterfaceIdiom]==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
 {
     if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f)
     {


     }
     else
     {
         //iphone 3.5 inch screen
     }
 }
 else
 {
        //[ipad]
 }
```

my answer:-
[Detect device type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139430/objective-c-how-detect-iphone-iphone5-and-ipad/13139561#13139561)

Comment: Please don't compare `float`s using `==`, it's unsafe. You better use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 567`.

Comment: There are rumors next iPod will have 5" screen so if you want to make an app for future this will cause little prob

Comment: @H2CO3 is correct! or just compare it with float literal,
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568.0f

Comment: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height > 567 doesn't work properly if iPhone app is running in frame on iPad

Answer (score 13):

This works just fine:

```
if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
    NSLog(@"IPAD");
}else{
     NSLog(@"IPHONE");
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Just adding to @Mohammad Kamran Usmani answer. More specific iPhone types:

```
@import UIKit;

//Check which iPhone it is
double screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    NSLog(@"All iPads");
} else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    if(screenHeight == 480) {
        NSLog(@"iPhone 4/4S");
        smallFonts = true;
    } else if (screenHeight == 568) {
        NSLog(@"iPhone 5/5S/SE");
        smallFonts = true;
    } else if (screenHeight == 667) {
        NSLog(@"iPhone 6/6S");
    } else if (screenHeight == 736) {
        NSLog(@"iPhone 6+, 6S+");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Others");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the following code:

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

- (NSString *)machineName
{
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine
                                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    if ([temp rangeOfString:@"iPod"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        return @"iPod";
    }

    if ([temp rangeOfString:@"iPad"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        return @"iPad";
    }

    if ([temp rangeOfString:@"iPhone"].location != NSNotFound)
    {
        return @"iPhone";
    }

    return @"Unknown device";
}
```

Comment: Instead of `if (!(stuff == bar))`, use the more readable `if (stuff != bar)`. Please!

Comment: Sorry my bad will take care if future

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code

```
if(screenSize.width==2048 && screenSize.height==1536)
{
   LetterParams.DeviceType=1;//IPadRetina
}
else if(screenSize.width==2048/2 && screenSize.height==1536/2)
{
   LetterParams.DeviceType=2;//IPad Non-Retina
}
else if(screenSize.width==1136 && screenSize.height==640)
{
   LetterParams.DeviceType=3;//IPhoneRetina
}
else
{
   LetterParams.DeviceType=4;//IPhone & Ipod
}
```

Comment: Comparing float values is quite unsafe. Depending on the mood of the CPU you're going to find that you're going to get a lot of false negatives in those if conditions, leading them to incorrectly going into the 'else'

Answer (score 2):

I'm with other guys are maintaining the code on **GitHub** so please take the latest code from there. We're continuously adding new devices in the list.

**Objective-C** : [GitHub/DeviceUtil](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/DeviceUtil)

**Swift** : [GitHub/DeviceGuru](https://github.com/InderKumarRathore/DeviceGuru)

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

- (NSString*)hardwareDescription {
    NSString *hardware = [self hardwareString];
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"]) return @"iPhone 2G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"]) return @"iPhone 3G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"]) return @"iPhone 4";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"]) return @"iPhone 4S";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"]) return @"iPhone 5";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"]) return @"iPodTouch 1G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"]) return @"iPodTouch 2G";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"]) return @"iPad";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"]) return @"iPad Mini";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"]) return @"iPad Air WIFI";
    //there are lots of other strings too, checkout the github repo
    //link is given at the top of this answer

    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"i386"]) return @"Simulator";
    if ([hardware isEqualToString:@"x86_64"]) return @"Simulator";

    return nil;
}

- (NSString*)hardwareString {
    size_t size = 100;
    char *hw_machine = malloc(size);
    int name[] = {CTL_HW,HW_MACHINE};
    sysctl(name, 2, hw_machine, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *hardware = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:hw_machine];
    free(hw_machine);
    return hardware;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that I came up with that focuses on key devices for screen measurement functions. It is a quick way to determine what you need. This will detect up to iPhone 5 and 5th Gen. iPod touches.

```
typedef enum{
   iPadRetina,iPadNoRetina,iPhoneiPod35InchRetina,iPhoneiPod35InchNoRetina,iPhoneiPod4InchRetina}DeviceType;

-(void)yourCustomFunctionThatNeedsToKnowDeviceType
{
    NSLog(@"device type = %i",[self getDeviceType]);

    switch ([self getDeviceType])
    {
        case iPadRetina:
        {
            NSLog(@"This device is one of the following: iPad 3, iPad 4");
            break;
        }
        case iPadNoRetina:
        {
            NSLog(@"This device is one of the following: iPad 1, iPad 2, iPad mini");
            break;
        }
        case iPhoneiPod35InchRetina:
        {
            NSLog(@"This device is one of the following: iPhone 4/4S or iPod Touch 4th Generation");
            break;
        }
        case iPhoneiPod35InchNoRetina:
        {
            NSLog(@"This device is one of the following: iPhone 3G/3GS or iPod Touch 3rd Generation");
            break;
        }
        case iPhoneiPod4InchRetina:
        {
            NSLog(@"This device is one of the following: iPhone 5 or iPod Touch 5th Generation");
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(int)getDeviceType
{
    // Get the ratio of the device's screen (height/width)
    CGFloat screenRatio = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height/[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;

    // Initialize return value to negative value
    DeviceType type = -1;
    if(screenRatio > 1.5)
    {
        /*
            4.0-Inch Screen
            This implies that the device is either an iPhone 5 or a 5th generation iPod
            Retina display is implicit
         */
        type = iPhoneiPod4InchRetina;
    }
    else
    {
        /*
            Device must be iPad 1/2/3/4/mini or iPhone 4/4S or iPhone 3G/3GS
         */

        // Take a screenshot to determine if the device has retina display or not
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
        [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        UIImage *scaleCheckImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            /*
                Device must be iPad 1/2/3/4/mini
             */
            if(scaleCheckImage.scale == 1)
            {
                // iPad 1/2/mini (No Retina)
                type = iPadNoRetina;
            }
            else if(scaleCheckImage.scale == 2)
            {
                // iPad 3/4 (Retina)
                type = iPadRetina;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            /*
                Device must be iPhone 4/4S or iPhone 3G/3GS or iPod Touch 3rd Generation or iPod Touch 4th Generation
             */
            if(scaleCheckImage.scale == 1)
            {
                // iPhone 3G/3GS or iPod Touch 3rd Generation (No Retina)
                type = iPhoneiPod35InchNoRetina;
            }
            else if(scaleCheckImage.scale == 2)
            {
                // iPhone 4/4S or iPod Touch 4th Generation (Retina)
                type = iPhoneiPod35InchRetina;
            }
        }
    }
    return type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)  
{
    NSLog(@"All iPads");  
}  
else
{
    else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()== UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        if( screenHeight > 480 && screenHeight < 667 )
        {
            NSLog(@"iPhone 5/5s/6");
        }
        else if ( screenHeight > 480 && screenHeight < 736 )
        {
            NSLog(@"Other iPhones Resizable");
        }
        else if ( screenHeight > 480 )
        {
            NSLog(@"iPhone 6 +");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"iPhone 4s and others");
        }
    }
```