# How to find whether the device is iPhone or iPad

Tags: ios, bash, instruments

I am trying to check whether the connected device is iPhone or iPad. I am able to print the device udid. But is there anyway we can see the device is iPad or iPhone using shell script or any other way.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372906/to-detect-ios-device-type

Comment: @sanman is there any way I can do this using bash script

Comment: Still unclear about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @sanman I am trying to above operation using bash script..so that it gives me an output whether the connected device is iPhone or iPad or both

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know solution for this my friend.Hope web helps you :)