# How can we load user interface on in iPhone application without using nib file?

Tags: ios, user-interface, nib

How can we load user interface on in iPhone application without using nib file?
I want to load user interface of application using .m file .Is it possible? how can we do that.

Comment: you can create `uiview` programatically...

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS - Support iPad & iPhone without using nib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401659/ios-support-ipad-iphone-without-using-nib)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it programmatically, the [`loadView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView) method is intended for creating views when not using NIBs or storyboards. Just write a `loadView` in your view controller and create your views there. Or have the `loadView` create an instance of your `UIView` subclass, and put the bulk of the code for your custom view in that `UIView` subclass. That's an alternative to using Interface Builder to build a NIB or storyboard.

If you do it in `loadView`, you just make sure to set `self.view` to be the view you created, and then the rest of your view controller code can reference `view` property like it would otherwise.

---

See the [Creating a View Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerPGforiOSLegacy/BasicViewControllers/BasicViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011381-CH101-SW36) section of the legacy *View Controller Programming Guide.* It outlines the basic process and provides a code sample. Admittedly, some of that legacy document is not entirely relevant (e.g. notably, views aren't "unloaded" under memory pressure and thus any references to `viewDidUnload` are no longer relevant), but it gives some context to programmatically created view hierarchies.

The [A View Controller Instantiates Its View Hierarchy When Its View is Accessed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW2) [broken link] section of that guide used to outline the basic flow:

[image]

---

By way of example, here is a Swift 3 example `loadView` for a view controller that programmatically creates its view hierarchy:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var containerView: UIView!
    weak var button: UIButton!

    // Note, when programmatically creating views, you:
    //
    //  - Implement the view hierarchy in `loadView` (not to be confused with `viewDidLoad`)
    //  - Must set `view` property
    //  - Must not call `super.loadView`
    //
    // This example creates a `view` for the view controller, and adds two subviews, a container and a button.
    // Note, the "container" isn't really needed, but I just did it so I could visually demonstrate that the
    // `frame` of the view was set properly. That's why I set it to be a different color of the main `view`
    // and inset it.

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6000000238, green: 0.6000000238, blue: 0.6000000238, alpha: 1)

        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2549019754, green: 0.2745098174, blue: 0.3019607961, alpha: 1)
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        self.containerView = containerView

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle("Back", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        containerView.addSubview(button)
        self.button = button

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: -10),
            containerView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 10),
            containerView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10),

            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerYAnchor)
        ])

    }

    func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        // do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Also note that you should *not* call `[super loadView]` from your own `loadView` method.

Comment: Agreed. The [Creating a View Programmatically](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW36) in the _View Controller Programming Guide_ provides an example `loadView` method (and reiterates rmaddy's point).

Answer (score 2):

```
Sample *sample = [[Sample alloc]init];
sample.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[sample.view addSubView:aLabel];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:sample animated:YES]; //or 
[self presentViewController:sample animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It's just an example. Here Sample is UIViewController class without a Nib file. You can handle it how you handle UIViewController class with a Nib file.

Answer (score 1):

Add view controller without xib. Then you can programatically add views.
Eg.

In **viewDidLoad** method :

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 10, 480, 320);  //giveframe for full screen
[self.view addSubView:view];
```

similarly for buttons, labels etc. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

Override loadView in your UIViewController subclass. Initialize a view and any subviews you want. Make sure this method sets the view property of your view controller.